# ui-select with two images

Tags: angularjs, ui-select

http://plnkr.co/edit/8Uks2e7tJ78Ax5bMbup2?p=preview

I want to add two icons to each item.
I make this:

```
<ui-select-choices repeat="lang in language_list">
  <img ng-src="{{ lang.url }}" />
  <img ng-src="{{ lang.url }}" />
  <div ng-bind-html="lang.name | highlight: $select.search" style="display: inline"></div>
</ui-select-choices>
```

But after selection of the item the is no second image in the selected control. How can I get two images in it?

Answer (score 0):

I added this code to the controller:

```
$scope.onSelected = function (selectedItem) {
    //do selectedItem.PropertyName like selectedItem.Name or selectedItem.Key 
    //whatever property your list has.

    var result = document.getElementsByClassName("select2-chosen")[1];
    var contentTr = angular.element('<img class="ng-scope" ng-src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stevenrskelton/flag-icon/master/png/16/country-4x3/gb.png" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stevenrskelton/flag-icon/master/png/16/country-4x3/gb.png">');

    if (angular.element(result).children().length > 2) {
        angular.element(result).children()[0].remove();
    }
    var wrappedResult = angular.element(result).prepend(contentTr);
}
```

And added this code:

```
on-select="onSelected($item)"
```

to the ui-select html as attribute.